# How to assign date/time to specific item in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I'm developing a simple To do App. The recyclerview gets items from Sqlite datebase.
By clicking the specific item, i want to assign date from Calendar to that item. Now i want to schedule each item in recyclerview with date. I'm facing problem to assign date/time to specific item because when i add date, it shows as next item in recyclerview

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder holder, final int position) {
        final InboxViewModel inboxViewModel = (InboxViewModel) arrayList.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText(inboxViewModel.getText());
        holder.date.setText(inboxViewModel.getDate());
        setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
MainClass is:
            public class InboxFragment extends Fragment{
        RecyclerView inbox_recyclerview;Inbox_Adapter adapter;
            ArrayList arrayList;
        String myId,myTask,myDate; int pos;String dt;
            MyDatabase db;
            private InboxViewModel inboxViewModel;
            FragmentHelper fragmentHelper; BottomSheetListener bottomSheetListener;
         RelativeLayout relativeLayout; DataController dataController;
         ActivityMain activityMain;

            @Override
            public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
                super.onAttach(context);
                fragmentHelper = (FragmentHelper) context;
                bottomSheetListener=(BottomSheetListener)context;
                dataController=(DataController)context;
                activityMain=(ActivityMain)context;

            }



            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                     ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);
                relativeLayout=root.findViewById(R.id.relative1);
                arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
                inbox_recyclerview=root.findViewById(R.id.inbox_recycler);
                inbox_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                inbox_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
               // dataController.onGetData();

                MyDatabase myDatabase = new MyDatabase(getContext());
                Cursor c = myDatabase.getData();
                if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no data available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            myId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(myDatabase.id));
                           myTask = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(myDatabase.task_col));
                         myDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(myDatabase.date_col));
                            inboxViewModel =new InboxViewModel(myTask,myId,myDate);
                            arrayList.add(inboxViewModel);

                        } while (c.moveToNext());
                        {

                            adapter=new Inbox_Adapter(getActivity(),arrayList,fragmentHelper,bottomSheetListener);
                            inbox_recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        }
                    }


                    inbox_recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                    inbox_recyclerview.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

                return root;
            }


    }
    MainFragmentClass is:
    public class InboxFragment extends Fragment{
    RecyclerView inbox_recyclerview;Inbox_Adapter adapter;
        ArrayList arrayList;
    String myId,myTask,myDate; int pos;String dt;
        MyDatabase db;
        private InboxViewModel inboxViewModel;
        FragmentHelper fragmentHelper; BottomSheetListener bottomSheetListener;
     RelativeLayout relativeLayout; DataController dataController;
     ActivityMain activityMain;

        @Override
        public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            fragmentHelper = (FragmentHelper) context;
            bottomSheetListener=(BottomSheetListener)context;
            dataController=(DataController)context;
            activityMain=(ActivityMain)context;

        }



        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);
            relativeLayout=root.findViewById(R.id.relative1);
            arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
            inbox_recyclerview=root.findViewById(R.id.inbox_recycler);
            inbox_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            inbox_recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
           // dataController.onGetData();

            MyDatabase myDatabase = new MyDatabase(getContext());
            Cursor c = myDatabase.getData();
            if (c.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "no data available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        myId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(myDatabase.id));
                       myTask = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(myDatabase.task_col));
                     myDate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(myDatabase.date_col));
                        inboxViewModel =new InboxViewModel(myTask,myId,myDate);
                        arrayList.add(inboxViewModel);

                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                    {

                        adapter=new Inbox_Adapter(getActivity(),arrayList,fragmentHelper,bottomSheetListener);
                        inbox_recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You should use POJO class and custom layout in which you can set values for main text, date & time . Populate the recycler view using arraylist of POJO type. Also share some of your code that you have tried to populate your Recycler View .It will help to get more accurate answers

Comment: Can you share your code here

Comment: now check please